# Get the stock price at the end of specific period using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Given a series of closing stock prices how does one get the price at the end of a month and week by symbol specifically if the last given price may not fall at the end of the month or week.   Here is a sample data set.

```
SYMBOL  PRICE   DATE
MSFT    30  8/23/2014
MSFT    31  8/27/2014
MSFT    32  8/31/2014
MSFT    29  9/4/2014
MSFT    32  9/8/2014
MSFT    28  9/12/2014
MSFT    27  9/16/2014
MSFT    31  9/20/2014
MSFT    32  9/24/2014
MSFT    27  9/28/2014
MSFT    32  10/2/2014
MSFT    33  10/6/2014
MSFT    28  10/10/2014
MSFT    32  10/14/2014
GOOG    130 8/23/2014
GOOG    131 8/27/2014
GOOG    132 8/31/2014
GOOG    129 9/4/2014
GOOG    132 9/8/2014
GOOG    128 9/12/2014
GOOG    127 9/16/2014
GOOG    131 9/20/2014
GOOG    132 9/24/2014
GOOG    127 9/28/2014
GOOG    132 10/2/2014
GOOG    133 10/6/2014
GOOG    128 10/10/2014
GOOG    132 10/14/2014
AAPL    530 8/23/2014
AAPL    531 8/27/2014
AAPL    532 8/31/2014
AAPL    529 9/4/2014
AAPL    532 9/8/2014
AAPL    528 9/12/2014
AAPL    527 9/16/2014
AAPL    531 9/20/2014
AAPL    532 9/24/2014
AAPL    527 9/28/2014
AAPL    532 10/2/2014
AAPL    533 10/6/2014
AAPL    528 10/10/2014
AAPL    532 10/14/2014
```

Comment: And what would you expect to see as the result based on this sample data?

Comment: Look at [`DAYPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use of row_number() will help you arrive at "most recent" (or "latest") by symbol, or symbol and month or symbol and week; through these:

```
select
*
from (
      select
          *
          , row_number() over(partition by symbol order by [Date] DESC) as rn
      from closings
     ) as L
where rn = 1
order by symbol
;

select
*
from (
      select
          *
          , row_number() over(partition by symbol, year([date]), month([date]) order by [Date] DESC) as rn
      from closings
     ) as L
where rn = 1
order by symbol, [Date]
;

select
*
from (
      select
          *
          , row_number() over(partition by symbol, year([date]), datepart(week,[date]) order by [Date] DESC) as rn
      from closings
     ) as L
where rn = 1
order by symbol, [Date]
;
```

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0902b/6)</kbd>